# How to add a service module in wildfly-swarm with .war packaging?

Tags: java, maven, wildfly-swarm

I added jdbc driver in pom.xml:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
    <version>4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And I add in project-defaults.yml:

```
swarm:
  datasources:
    data-sources:
      erp-ds:
        driver-name: sqlserver
        connection-url: jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=COMPARTILHADO
        user-name: teste
        password: teste
    jdbc-drivers:
      sqlserver:
        driver-class-name: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
        xa-datasource-name: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerXADataSource
        driver-module-name: com.microsoft.sqlserver
```

but I run application it throws exception:

```
2017-06-14 13:09:54,337 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
    ("data-source" => "erp-ds")
]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.jdbc-driver.sqlserver"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "jboss.driver-demander.java:jboss/datasources/erp-ds is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.sqlserver]",
        "org.wildfly.data-source.erp-ds is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.sqlserver]"
    ]
}
```

In Wildfly I has to add driver in standalone.xml but I don't know in wildfly-swarm. In development stage I add a DatasourcesFraction with jdbcDriver, its easy, but when I build .war and I run uberjar `java -jar ??????-swarm.jar` throws exception above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're actually providing too much information in project-defaults.yml!

```
swarm:
  datasources:
    data-sources:
      erp-ds:
        driver-name: sqlserver
        connection-url: jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=COMPARTILHADO
        user-name: teste
        password: teste
```

should be all you need.

By adding com.microsoft.sqlserver:sqljdbc4:4.0 as a project dependency, WF Swarm will automatically create the JDBC Driver configuration for you.

That may not solve the particular issue you're having, so I'd take a look at the WAR that WF Swarm modifies (the one without the .original suffix) in /target and see whether your jdbc jar is inside WEB-INF/lib.

Comment: Thanks. I reconstructed my pom.xml and I simplified many things here and it worked.